# Kubernetes manifest apiserver, no forwarding?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I am working on building a kubernetes cluster on AWS using terraform, by reverse engineering the kube-aws script here:

https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/kubernetes-on-aws.html

However when it is created, the kube-apiserver pod does not forward 443 to the host, so the api cannot be reached (it *does* forward 8080 to 127.0.0.1)

The manifest in question:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kube-apiserver
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
  containers:
  - name: kube-apiserver
    image: gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:${K8S_VER}
    command:
    - /hyperkube
    - apiserver
    - --bind-address=0.0.0.0
    - --etcd_servers=${ETCD_ENDPOINTS}
    - --allow-privileged=true
    - --service-cluster-ip-range=${SERVICE_IP_RANGE}
    - --secure_port=443
    - --advertise-address=${ADVERTISE_IP}
    - --admission-control=NamespaceLifecycle,NamespaceExists,LimitRanger,SecurityContextDeny,ServiceAccount,ResourceQuota
    - --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver.pem
    - --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-key.pem
    - --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem
    - --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-key.pem
    - --cloud-provider=aws
    ports:
    - containerPort: 443
      hostPort: 443
      name: https
    - containerPort: 8080
      hostPort: 8080
      name: local
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/ssl
      name: ssl-certs-kubernetes
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
      name: ssl-certs-host
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/ssl
    name: ssl-certs-kubernetes
  - hostPath:
      path: /usr/share/ca-certificates
    name: ssl-certs-host
```

Some output:

```
ip-10-0-0-50 core # docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                       COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
47d36516ada9        gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.0.7   "/hyperkube apiserve   18 minutes ago      Up 18 minutes                           k8s_kube-apiserver.daa12bc1_kube-apiserver-ip-10-0-0-50.eu-west-1.compute.internal_kube-system_0ff7c6642d467da6eec9af9d96af0622_b88e9ada                     
48f85774ff5c        gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.0.7   "/hyperkube schedule   38 minutes ago      Up 38 minutes                           k8s_kube-scheduler.cca58e1_kube-scheduler-ip-10-0-0-50.eu-west-1.compute.internal_kube-system_8aa2dd5e26e716aa54d97e2691e100e0_d6865ecb                      
1242789081a9        gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.0.7   "/hyperkube controll   38 minutes ago      Up 38 minutes                           k8s_kube-controller-manager.9ddfd2a0_kube-controller-manager-ip-10-0-0-50.eu-west-1.compute.internal_kube-system_66bae8c21c0937cc285af054be236103_16b6bfb9   
2ebafb2a3413        gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.0.7   "/hyperkube proxy --   38 minutes ago      Up 38 minutes                           k8s_kube-proxy.de5c3084_kube-proxy-ip-10-0-0-50.eu-west-1.compute.internal_kube-system_e6965a2424ca55206c44b02ad95f479e_dacdc559                             
ade9cd54f391        gcr.io/google_containers/pause:0.8.0        "/pause"               38 minutes ago      Up 38 minutes                           k8s_POD.e4cc795_kube-scheduler-ip-10-0-0-50.eu-west-1.compute.internal_kube-system_8aa2dd5e26e716aa54d97e2691e100e0_b72b8dba                                  
78633207462f        gcr.io/google_containers/pause:0.8.0        "/pause"               38 minutes ago      Up 38 minutes                           k8s_POD.e4cc795_kube-controller-manager-ip-10-0-0-50.eu-west-1.compute.internal_kube-system_66bae8c21c0937cc285af054be236103_71057c93                        
b97643a86f51        gcr.io/google_containers/podmaster:1.1      "/podmaster --etcd-s   39 minutes ago      Up 39 minutes                           k8s_controller-manager-elector.663462cc_kube-podmaster-ip-10-0-0-50.eu-west-1.compute.internal_kube-system_8e57c3cada4c03fae8d01352505c25e5_0bb98126         
0859c891679e        gcr.io/google_containers/podmaster:1.1      "/podmaster --etcd-s   39 minutes ago      Up 39 minutes                           k8s_scheduler-elector.468957a0_kube-podmaster-ip-10-0-0-50.eu-west-1.compute.internal_kube-system_8e57c3cada4c03fae8d01352505c25e5_fe401f47                  
e948e718f3d8        gcr.io/google_containers/pause:0.8.0        "/pause"               39 minutes ago      Up 39 minutes                           k8s_POD.e4cc795_kube-apiserver-ip-10-0-0-50.eu-west-1.compute.internal_kube-system_0ff7c6642d467da6eec9af9d96af0622_774d1393                                 
eac6b18c0900        gcr.io/google_containers/pause:0.8.0        "/pause"               39 minutes ago      Up 39 minutes                           k8s_POD.e4cc795_kube-podmaster-ip-10-0-0-50.eu-west-1.compute.internal_kube-system_8e57c3cada4c03fae8d01352505c25e5_949f1945                                 
6411aed07d40        gcr.io/google_containers/pause:0.8.0        "/pause"               39 minutes ago      Up 39 minutes                           k8s_POD.e4cc795_kube-proxy-ip-10-0-0-50.eu-west-1.compute.internal_kube-system_e6965a2424ca55206c44b02ad95f479e_160a3b0f

ip-10-0-0-50 core # netstat -lnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10252         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1818/hyperkube      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7966/hyperkube      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10248         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1335/kubelet        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10249         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1800/hyperkube      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10251         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1820/hyperkube      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      610/systemd-resolve 
tcp6       0      0 :::10255                :::*                    LISTEN      1335/kubelet        
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1/systemd           
tcp6       0      0 :::55447                :::*                    LISTEN      1800/hyperkube      
tcp6       0      0 :::42274                :::*                    LISTEN      1800/hyperkube      
tcp6       0      0 :::10250                :::*                    LISTEN      1335/kubelet        
tcp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                    LISTEN      610/systemd-resolve 
udp        0      0 10.0.0.50:68            0.0.0.0:*                           576/systemd-network 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8285            0.0.0.0:*                           1456/flanneld       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*                           610/systemd-resolve 
udp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                                610/systemd-resolve 
udp6       0      0 :::52627                :::*                                1800/

ip-10-0-0-50 core # docker logs 47d36516ada9
I1127 23:47:15.421827       1 aws.go:489] Zone not specified in     configuration file; querying AWS metadata service
I1127 23:47:15.523047       1 aws.go:595] AWS cloud filtering on tags: map[KubernetesCluster:kubernetes]
I1127 23:47:15.692595       1 master.go:273] Node port range unspecified. Defaulting to 30000-32767.
[restful] 2015/11/27 23:47:15 log.go:30: [restful/swagger] listing is available at https://10.0.0.50:443/swaggerapi/
[restful] 2015/11/27 23:47:15 log.go:30: [restful/swagger] https://10.0.0.50:443/swaggerui/ is mapped to folder /swagger-ui/
E1127 23:47:15.718842       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.ResourceQuota: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/resourcequotas: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
E1127 23:47:15.719005       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.Secret: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/secrets?fieldSelector=type%3Dkubernetes.io%2Fservice-account-token: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
E1127 23:47:15.719150       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.ServiceAccount: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/serviceaccounts: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
E1127 23:47:15.719307       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.LimitRange: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/limitranges: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
E1127 23:47:15.719457       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.Namespace: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/namespaces: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
E1127 23:47:15.719506       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.Namespace: Get http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/namespaces: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused
I1127 23:47:15.767717       1 server.go:441] Serving securely on 0.0.0.0:443
I1127 23:47:15.767796       1 server.go:483] Serving insecurely on 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it immediately occurred to me to check the certificates that I was using after posting this (Rubberduck ftw.)

Turns out I was merely passing the wrong file to the tls-cert-file= argument.

After correcting it to the right one , everything started working straight away!